# Horizontal barplot for comparison two data - based on ratio

Tags: r

I would like to create a horizontal barplot to compare two of my tables. I already did the comparison and created a table with ratio.

That's how the data looks like:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(Name=c('Mazda RX4','Mazda RX4 Wag','Datsun 710','Hornet 4 Drive',
'Hornet Sportabout','Valiant','Duster 360','Merc 240D','Merc 230','Merc 280','Merc 280C',
'Merc 450SE','Merc 450SL','Merc 450SLC','Cadillac Fleetwood','Lincoln Continental',
'Chrysler Imperial','Fiat 128','Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla'),ratio=c(1.393319198903125,
0.374762569687951,0.258112791829808,0.250298480396529,1.272180366473129,0.318000456484454,
0.264074483447591,0.350798965144559,2.310541690719624,1.314300844213157,1.18061486696761,
0.281581177092538,0.270164442687919,2.335578882236703,2.362339701969396,1.307731925943769,
0.347550384302281,0.232276047899868,0.125643566969327,0.281209747680576),Freq=c(2L,9L,2L,2L,
4L,2L,2L,3L,3L,5L,2L,2L,2L,7L,2L,4L,4L,2L,2L,4L)),.Names=c('Name','ratio','Freq'),class=
'data.frame',row.names=c(NA,20L))
```

I would like to achieve something like that:

[image: Example]

In the middle I would put 1. Based on the calculated ratio I would like to put the proper scale which goes up to 3 to the right for example and to 0 to the left (can be different of course).

Each of the cars should have a separate bar. It will give 20 bars on this plot.

Additional thing would be to put the numbers from column `Freq` on the plots. It's not obligatory but would help.

Comment: So for example for Mazda RX4 the bar would from zero to ~1.4 and then with another color, to 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: plot]

```
## plot precomputations
yexpand <- 0.2;
barheight <- 0.8;
xlim <- c(0,3);
xticks <- seq(xlim[1L],xlim[2L],0.25);
ylim <- c(1-barheight/2-yexpand,nrow(data)+barheight/2+yexpand);
yticks <- seq_len(nrow(data));
cols <- c('#6F7EB3','#D05B5B');

## draw plot
par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1+c(0,3,0,0));
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xaxs='i',yaxs='i',axes=F,ann=F);
segments(xlim[1L],ylim[1L],xlim[1L],ylim[2L],xpd=NA);
axis(1L,xticks,cex.axis=0.7);
axis(2L,yticks,data$Name,las=2L,cex.axis=0.7);
mtext(expression(italic(Ratio)),1L,3);
mtext(expression(italic(Car)),2L,5.5);
mtext(data$Freq,4L,0.75,at=yticks,las=2L,cex=0.7);
y1 <- seq_len(nrow(data))-barheight/2;
y2 <- seq_len(nrow(data))+barheight/2;
rect(xlim[1L],y1,data$ratio,y2,col=cols[1L],lwd=0.5);
rect(data$ratio,y1,xlim[2L],y2,col=cols[2L],lwd=0.5);
abline(v=1);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't really see how that plot makes much sense with your data, as there is no quantity that adds up to 1 (or a common total). It could make sense with proportions, not so much with ratio's. I might be missing something... Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)

r <- range(d$ratio)
br <- seq(floor(r[1]), ceiling(r[2]), 0.5)

ggplot(d, aes(x = Name, y = ratio - 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab('ratio') + xlab('car') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = br - 1, labels = br) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Add `geom_text(aes(label = Freq), y = r[2] - 0.95)` for the labels on the right side.

Or if you want to center the value of 1 (a bit more tricky):

```
r <- range(d$ratio)
m <- ceiling(max(abs(range(d$ratio))))
br <- seq(-m + 1, m - 1, 0.25)

ggplot(d, aes(x = Name, y = ratio - 1)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = Freq), y = m - 1.1) +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab('ratio') + xlab('car') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = br, labels = br + 1, limits = c(-m + 1, m - 1), 
                     expand = c(0, 0)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: That could be useful for me as well. Do you know how to "force" the plot to put `1` in the middle and do 0.25 breaks ? I tried on my own but without success.